# jquery mobile json filter?

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

So I have some JSON data which I acquire using $.getJSON. 
I have a menu that represents some categories. I need a function that can filter the JSON in my listview.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQM offers some functionality to parse JSON into pages:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

Would something like this be what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmmm, possibly - I'm just not sure how to apply it to my particular JSON model, which is coming from a URL, and isn't structured in a hierarchal format like in that example. Basically my JSON looks like {id:value, title:value, category:value} - I need a function that can filter onclick by category. Thanks for the link anyhow!